# Custom Attribute field not saving to DB during onepage checkout Magento 1.6?

Tags: mysql, magento

Can anybody help with this ?

I have created a new module with 2 custom fields all seems to be working ok accept one of the fields will not save to the db through the onepage checkout process ?

I can enter data through the registration page (register.phtml) and edit the data through the edit account page (edit.phtml) this all saves to the db ok.

One of the fields is a select field that gets option from Model/Entity this field saves ok, both fields have the same entries in the config.xml file.

I have tried various versions of input in the billing.phtml

```
    <?php if(!$this->isCustomerLoggedIn()): ?>
    <li>    
    <label for="billing:childname" class="required"><em>*</em>
    <?php echo   $this->__('Childs Name') ?>
    </label>
    <div class="input-box">
    <input type="text" name="billing[childname]" id="billing:childname" 
    value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getQuote()->getCustomerChildname()) ?>" 
    title="<?php echo $this->__('Childs Name') ?>" 
    class="input-text validate-text required-entry" />
    </div> 
    </li>
```

also:   value="htmlEscape($this->getCustomer()->getChildname()) ?>"

But nothing I try seems to work any ideas what mite be going wrong ??

Many thanks

Comment: It looks like you are trying to save the attribute as part of the billing address, but you are referring to the attribute as belonging to the customer object.  Is it an address attribute or is it a customer attribute?

Comment: @JoeConstant , sorry for the delay in replying , I'm trying to save it as a Customer Attribute it has an entity_type_id = 1 ? thanks

Answer (score 1):

In order to save your 'childname' attribute in DB we need to save this value in 'sales_flat_quote' table first.

Please follow the steps to get the field to be saved in DB.

**Step1:** Add new column in `sales_flat_quote` by running below query.

```
ALTER TABLE  `sales_flat_quote` ADD  `customer_childname` INT NOT NULL
```

**Step2:** Now goto your module `config.xml` file and paste below `fieldsets` code in global block, if you don't have own module then paste it in any other module.

```
<global>
     //.....................
     <fieldsets>
       <checkout_onepage_quote>
         <customer_childname>
             <to_customer>childname</to_customer>
         </customer_childname>
       </checkout_onepage_quote>
        <customer_account>
            <childname>
                <to_quote>customer_childname</to_quote>
            </childname>
        </customer_account>     
      </fieldsets>
      //......................
</global>
```

Now check it :)